# Find upper and lower bound for $u(3/4)$ where $u$ is a positive harmonic function on unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

> Let $u$ be positive harmonic function in the unit disk such that $u(0)=\alpha$. Find upper and lower bound for number $u(3/4)$.

I tried to find an example, that is positive, harmonic( realvalued? and $\Delta u=0$) in the unit disk such that $u(0)=\alpha$. But this is closest I came; let $f(z)=x^2-y^2+\alpha$ then it satisfies all the conditions except that f(z)>0 is not true when $x<y$. So I ask if you can find example that satisfies the conditions.
This assignment is contradictory, because $u>0$ but still you got $|z| \leq 1$. $|u|>0$ is of course trivially true, but I think in this case you want $u>0$.

Comment: Hint #1: $u(0)$ is equal to the average of $u$ on the unit circle (let's pretend $u$ is continuous on the closed disk; it does not change the answer). Hint #2: [Poisson integral formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel).

Comment: 5pm: I don't see how to procede. How do you use those hints to evaluate upper and lower bounds?

Answer (score 2):

Every positive harmonic function on unit disk $D$ is the Poisson integral of some measure $\mu$ on $\partial D$: 
$$u(re^{i\theta}) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1-r^2}{1-2r\cos (\theta-t)+r^2}\,d\mu(t)\tag1$$
The condition $u(0)=\alpha$ says that $\mu(\partial D)  = 2\pi\alpha$. Subject to this condition, you want to estimate
$$u(3/4) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1-(3/4)^2}{1-\frac32\cos t+\frac{9}{16}}\,d\mu(t)\tag2$$
The only thing that matters is that the integrand in (2) has maximum when $t=0$ and minimum when $t=\pi$. So, given that the total mass of $\mu$ is constrained to be $2\pi\alpha$, we can maximize (2) by putting all this mass at the point $t=0$, and minimize by putting all of it at $t=\pi$. 
$$\frac{1-(3/4)^2}{1+\frac32 +\frac{9}{16}}\le u(3/4)\le \alpha \frac{1-(3/4)^2}{1-\frac32 +\frac{9}{16}}$$

Not  coincidentally,  the extremal functions are obtained by rotation and scaling of the Poisson kernel itself.